# sed command is not working in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, sed

There is one Jenkins pipeline running when I call a file using particular path, e.g: `./UI/specs/**/start.specs.js`, pipeline is running all the files inside the folder but I want to execute only single file called `start.specs.js`.

I think `sed` is not replacing the present calling function (`./UI/specs/**/start.specs.js`) properly in the file inside the `xcv.conf.js`.

```
sed -ri "/\\.\\/specs\\//s~\\./specs/\\*\\*/\\*\\.spec\\.js~${params.TEST}~" xcv.conf.js
```

Please help me how to run a single file on Jenkins using a parameter I specify and if there is any issue with this `sed` for not actively calling the mentioned file** I called on param. TEST while running the Build.

Comment: I don't think your problem statement is reproducible. Modifying your code programmatically is often an antipattern anyway; is there a reason you don't simply refactor the code so it executes a different payload when a particular command-line argument or environment variable is set, for example?

Comment: does using `${params.TEST}` works with jenkins? If so, then it may contain problematic characters for using in your `sed` expression (a dash for example).

Comment: @Fravadona you are correct the function is not accepting the value that i provide manually , how can i rectify that in Jenkins. To run only a single file to work instead of running all the files on that path!

Comment: @tripleee sorry I really don't get you am new to these scripting

Comment: Please review the guidance for providing a [mre]. For the alternate implementation, I'm not a Javascript developer, but something like `if (${env.testing} != "true") { do_stuff "./UI/specs/**/start.specs.js"; } else { do_stuff "start.specs.js"; }` in `xcv.conf.js`